# SSRS subreport instead of reportfooter

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a report that has variable coulmns and the report looks fine in preview.

But now I want to add a "Hazardous Notice" like a report footer but via using subreport.

And this Notice will be only having TEXT in it (no columns and rows)

I am able to drag the subreport from the tools beneath my main Matrix, but I am really confused that how can I get only TEXT in that HAZARDOUS NOTICE.. as it asks me to add parameters in it. Do I need to create a Parameter for that or not.. Please Help!!!

Comment: Do you know which subreport needs to be used? Are you creating a subreport or is it an existing one?

Comment: Hi Anup, I am creating a new one.

Comment: Means I am creating new subreport.

Comment: Have you created a report with the text in it? You can ignore the parameters in the subreport section.

Comment: actually my report as a whole is completed, which consists of header, body(matrix) and footer(date n time).. just need to add this NOTICE so that in preview I can see it in a footer level using subreport

Comment: Do you understand what is a subreport and how to use it?

Comment: Hi Anup, no not much actually. I know that we can use with the main report but here for my purpose I just want to show that Notice on each page of the report.